# How can I create a circle outline with a shadow in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need a circular `OutlinedButton` with an elevation but that property is not available for that widget. I'm trying to create a circle outline with a shadow and wrap it in a `GestureDetector` to achieve the same behavior but all options that I have tried have the shadow all the way to the center of the circle or don't have any shadow in the inner part of the circle.

This is the output that I'm looking for:

[image: circle with shadow]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: @pskink Could you write this as an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: check my answer: I added some params you can use (or not as they are optional)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a standard `OutlinedButton` widget with a modified `shape` property:

```
class RingBorder extends CircleBorder {
  const RingBorder({
    this.thickness = 12,
    this.color = Colors.blue,
    this.shadowColor = Colors.black,
    this.shadowRadius = 6,
    this.paintShadowCounter = 1,
  });

  final double thickness;
  final Color color;
  final Color shadowColor;
  final double shadowRadius;
  final int paintShadowCounter;

  @override
  CircleBorder copyWith({BorderSide? side, double? eccentricity}) => this;

  @override
  void paint(ui.Canvas canvas, ui.Rect rect, {ui.TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    final path = Path()
      ..fillType = PathFillType.evenOdd
      ..addOval(Rect.fromCircle(center: rect.center, radius: rect.shortestSide / 2 - shadowRadius))
      ..addOval(Rect.fromCircle(center: rect.center, radius: rect.shortestSide / 2 - shadowRadius - thickness));

    final paint = Paint()..color = color;
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    paint
      ..color = shadowColor
      ..maskFilter = MaskFilter.blur(BlurStyle.outer, shadowRadius);
    for (int i = 0; i < paintShadowCounter; i++) {
      canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }
  }
}
```

now you can use it as follows:

```
OutlinedButton(
  style: ButtonStyle(
    shape: MaterialStatePropertyAll(RingBorder(
      color: Colors.orange,
      paintShadowCounter: 4,
      shadowRadius: 12,
    )),
  ),
  onPressed: () => print('pressed'),
  child: Container(),
);
```

notice that all params are optional and contain some default values

Answer (score 2):

**Try This Code:**

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body:  Container(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
    child: IconButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      iconSize: 200,
      icon: const Icon(
        Icons.circle_outlined,
        shadows: [Shadow(blurRadius: 70)],
      ),
      color: Colors.blue,
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
[image]

Comment: "_the shadow all the way to the center of the circle or don't have any shadow in the inner part of the circle._" don't forget this part

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem because, as I stated in the question, it does not contain a shadow in the inner part of the circle

Comment: @MobinAnsar This is closer to what I'm looking for but this won't allow me to change the weight of the stroke. I could create my own Icon with the weight that I want but I'm trying to avoid that

Comment: @EddyTodd You can use the icon to manage weight.iconSize: 100,; property. This is exactly what you wanted.

Comment: @MobinAnsar how do I change that property?

Comment: @EddyTodd Just Change Icon size

Comment: @MobinAnsar that won't let me adjust the stroke weight. It would just grow as the icon grows but I won't be able to make a large icon with a thin border

Comment: ok alright as you want

Answer (score 1):

you can take IconButton and take *circle_outlined as icon* and give shadow as per your need:

```
IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    iconSize: 50,
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.circle_outlined,
                      shadows: [Shadow(blurRadius: 20)],
                    ),
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
```

Comment: This is very close to what I want but with this code I can't change the stroke weight of the circle

Answer (score 1):

Try below code hope its help to you. I have try same like as your shared image

```
  Container(
  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
  child: Container(
    height: 200,
    width: 200,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.9),
          spreadRadius: 6, //change on your need
          blurRadius: 10,
          offset: const Offset(0, 3),
        )
      ],
    ),
    child: Container(
      height: 200,
      width: 200,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        color: Colors.transparent,
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 5),
        boxShadow: const [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black26,
          ),
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.white,
            spreadRadius: -10.0, //change on your need
            blurRadius: 12.0,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Result-> [image]

Comment: This is very close to what I want but I need the background to be transparent

Comment: Yes in my code the background is already transparent, and change `Colors.transparent` to `Colors.white` in first container I have update my answer

Comment: The icon's background is not transparent, it's white. Changing the color to `Colors.transparent` will make the shadow fill all the circle

Comment: Yes got it please try to apply `Colors.transparent` for second container, it's working correctly in my side

Comment: It's not working on my side. Can you update the answer?

Comment: @EddyTodd please check my updated answer I also share my image also

Comment: Still not working. It shows a white background. If you set the scaffold color to black, the inner part of the circle will be white. This is not the desirable behavior. Ultimately, this button will be above an image, so I need it to be transparent. This approach won't work

Answer (score 0):

wrap the OutlinedButton in a Container and apply a BoxShadow to the Container.

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {},
  child: Container(
    width: 100.0,
    height: 100.0,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
          color: Colors.black26,
          blurRadius: 10.0,
          offset: Offset(0, 10),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    child: OutlinedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Text("Button"),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: you forgot to cover the part "the shadow all the way to the center of the circle or don't have any shadow in the inner part of the circle."

Comment: wrap the OutlinedButton widget in a ClipOval widget. This will clip the shadow and make it so it is only visible outside of the circular shape.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  body: InkWell( 
    onTap: () {},
    child: Container(
      height: 150,
      width: 150,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(100),
          ),
          border: Border.all(
              color: Color(0xff00AEEF), 
              width: 3.w),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.9),
              spreadRadius: 4,
              blurRadius: 10,
              offset: Offset(0, 3),
            )
          ]),
      child: OutlinedButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Text("You can add Text and icon"),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

Comment: As I stated in the question, I need the shadow in the inner part of the circle as well. This will create a widget with a white background but I need it to be transparent